# Dropdown be shrunk when display as flex

Tags: html, css, plotly, plotly-dash

I'm trying to arrange `html` and `components` inline and using `'display':'flex'` to make it but Dropdown components be shrunk. Below is my sample code:

```
import plotly.express as px
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from dash.exceptions import PreventUpdate

app = dash.Dash(__name__,external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.LUX])
app.layout = html.Div([
    dbc.Row([
        dbc.Col([
            html.H6('Input',style={'padding-top' : 10,'padding-right' : 2}),
            dcc.Input(type="number",id="input",value=4,min=3,style={'text-align':'center'})
        ],width={'size':2,"offset":0,'order':1},style={'text-align':'center','display':'flex'}),
        dbc.Col([
            html.H6('Template',style={'padding-top' : 10,'padding-right' : 2}),
            dcc.Dropdown(id='template',placeholder="Please select template",
                         options=[{'label': 'ggplot2', 'value': 'ggplot2'},
                                  {'label': 'plotly_white', 'value': 'plotly_white'}],
                         value='ggplot2',
                         multi=False,
                         disabled=False,
                         clearable=True,
                         searchable=True),
        ],width={'size':4,"offset":0,'order':1},style={'display':'flex'}),
    ], className='p-2 align-items-stretch')
])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=False,port=1118)
```

And here is the Ouput:
[image]

As you see, `Input` is normal but `Dropdown` be shrunk and I don't know why.
Actually I can add `dbc.Row` and `dbc.Col` to make it in one line but code look quite messy.

```
import plotly.express as px
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from dash.exceptions import PreventUpdate

app = dash.Dash(__name__,external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.LUX])
app.layout = html.Div([
    dbc.Row([
        dbc.Col([
            html.H6('Input',style={'padding-top' : 10,'padding-right' : 2}),
            dcc.Input(type="number",id="input",value=4,min=3,style={'text-align':'center'})
        ],width={'size':2,"offset":0,'order':1},style={'text-align':'center','display':'flex'}),
        dbc.Col([
            dbc.Row([
                dbc.Col([
                    html.H6('Template',style={'padding-top' : 10,'padding-right' : 2}),
                ],width={'size':4,"offset":0,'order':1},style={'text-align':'center'}),
                dbc.Col([
                    dcc.Dropdown(id='template',placeholder="Please select template",
                                 options=[{'label': 'ggplot2', 'value': 'ggplot2'},
                                          {'label': 'plotly_white', 'value': 'plotly_white'}],
                                 value='ggplot2',
                                 multi=False,
                                 disabled=False,
                                 clearable=True,
                                 searchable=True)
                ],width={'size':8,"offset":0,'order':1})
            ])
        ],width={'size':4,"offset":0,'order':1}),
    ], className='p-2 align-items-stretch')
])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=False,port=1118)
```

Output:
[image]
So what should I do if I want to arrange `html` and `Dropdown` in one line and it not be shrunk?

Thank you.

Comment: try `flex: 1` in dropdown

Comment: @MinSomai: It didn't work for me.

Comment: you would need to give a min width to the flex container - if you don't use flex wrap and there is not enough room for your elements, they will always overlap

Comment: try `flex: 1 0 auto`